# Error al loguear usuario al haber completado el registrado

Tags: php, mysql

Comunidad, el error que tengo es que el usuario al haber terminado el proceso de registro yo quiero que lo loguee de una vez sin necesidad de ir a una pagina de login, el codigo que estoy utilizando para ello es el siguiente:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
$names = $_POST['nombres'];
$pass = $_POST['password_user'];
$nie = $_POST['nie'];
$tlf = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$d_entrega = $_POST['address_entrega'];
$d_facturacion = $_POST['address_fact'];

$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombres,pass,nie,telefono,direccion_entrega,direccion_facturacion,email)
VALUES ('$names','$pass','$nie','$tlf','$d_entrega','$d_facturacion','$email')";

$sql = $con->query($query);

if($sql>0){
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$pass'";
    $sql2 = $con->query($query2);
    $result = $sql2->num_rows;
    echo $result;
    $datos = $sql2->fetch_assoc();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario']=$datos;
    header('Location:productos.php');
}
}
```

El num_rows me arroja >0 pero cuando hace la redirección me manda a la pagina sin la sesión iniciada. Como si no fuera logueado.

Comment: Es consciente que tiene gran vulnerabilidad para ataques de [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)? , además que ingresa el `email` en el campo `direccion_entrega` . Quizá deba ir al final ?

Comment: Estoy consciente de eso. Eso lo migrare a PDO. Lo que quiero es saber porque no me loguea al usuario al realizar el registro. Ya modifique lo del email y sigue haciendo lo mismo. Ya el echo del num_rows me muestra que si hay registros con esos datos, pero cuando hago el header location me redirecciona a la pagina pero sin la sesion iniciada

Comment: Ese último `if($sql2>0){..} else {...}` está de más . Antes de asignar a `$_SESSION['carrito'] = $datos;`  debe iniciar la sesión con `session_start();` y luego de asignar el array de datos , realiza la re dirección `header('Location:productos.php');`

Comment: Joel he editado la pregunta, ahora tengo el codigo asi. Ya arroja mayor que cero el num rows pero sigue sin loguearme.

Comment: Añadí una respuesta para resolver sus dudas o problemas. además modifiqué el código para emplear sentencias preparadas. algo  más seguro. Si tiene dudas no dude en comentar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar existía un error en el orden de los campos del `insert` lo cuál es un problema menor teniendo como máximo problema el código inseguro que está construyendo. Debería preparar sus sentencias.

Si la sesión no se muestra o tiene problemas era posiblemente porque no la había iniciado con `session_start()` , esto **`debería realizarlo en los dos archivos y en todos los que emplee sesiones`** en la actual y en `productos.php` *(al inicio del archivo)*

Otra consideración a tener en cuenta es. ¿ Es necesario realizar un `select` cuando está seguro que se registro el usuario? . Quizá puede obviar este paso. *(posible código final)*

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombres,pass,nie,telefono,direccion_entrega,
           direccion_facturacion,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $names ,$pass,$nie,$tlf,$d_entrega,$d_facturacion,$email);
    if($stmt->execute()){//Se inserto
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['carrito'] = array('email'=>$email,'pass'=>$pass);
        header('Location:script.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Joel. Ya ha funcionado. Y si tienes razon en lo del SELECT. Muchas Gracias